# Cannot read packageName - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mobile

I've checked and tried different solutions I ran into but none helped. I keep getting this error message and I checked to see if the manifest file was under /src/main and it was. [image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Below section in the `module` level build Gradle file should be moved to `project` level build Gradle file:

```
respositories{
       ...
}
```

and in your `module` level build Gradle file, check if there is a line on the top:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```